# Facing ORA-01722: invalid number error while selecting data from a table

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION XXCHR_FNC(
  P_EMP_ID         IN   NUMBER,
  P_COLUMN_NAME    IN   VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  lv_dyn_sql    VARCHAR2(2000):= NULL;
  lv_return_val VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  lv_dyn_sql:='SELECT :2 FROM thirty_days '
               || 'WHERE salesrep_id=:1';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_dyn_sql INTO lv_return_val
  USING P_EMP_ID,P_COLUMN_NAME;

  RETURN(lv_return_val);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Returning Error : '||SQLERRM);
    RETURN (SQLERRM);
END XXCHR_FNC;
```

Comment: There is no question here. What are you asking?

Comment: Apologies the issue is when i try to execute the above function i'm facing an error like ORA-01722: invalid number error while selecting data from a table. I have assigned correct datatypes to the variables please suggest here. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is a type of `salesrep_id` column ? And what value did you pass to `P_COLUMN_NAME` parameter ? I guess that `salesrep_id` is of number datatype, but you passed some string that cannot be converted to a number to `P_COLUMN_NAME`, and this was a reason of the error.

Comment: `ORA-01722: You executed a SQL statement that tried to convert a string to a number, but it was unsuccessful.` I would say that `P_EMP_ID` should be a string. Or convert it to a string before using it.

Comment: in salesrep_id im passing number and at parameter P_COLUMN_NAME i'm passing string(column_name) here the requirement is both column name and salesrep_id are dynamic in nature.

Comment: So `lv_dyn_sql` should be made based on what is enterd in your function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass a column name as a bind variable - if you do you will return the column name as a string literal rather than getting the value from the column. You need to use concatenation on the SQL string:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION XXCHR_FNC(
  P_EMP_ID         IN   NUMBER,
  P_COLUMN_NAME    IN   VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  lv_return_val VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'SELECT ' || P_COLUMN_NAME || ' FROM thirty_days WHERE salesrep_id=:1'
  INTO  lv_return_val
  USING P_EMP_ID;

  RETURN lv_return_val;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Returning Error : '||SQLERRM);
    RETURN SQLERRM;
END XXCHR_FNC;
/
```

**Testing**:

```
CREATE TABLE thirty_days (
  salesrep_id NUMBER(8,0),
  a VARCHAR2(20),
  b VARCHAR2(20),
  c VARCHAR2(20),
  d VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO thirty_days VALUES( 1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' );
```

**Output**:

```
SELECT xxchr_fnc( 1, 'a' ) FROM DUAL;

XXCHR_FNC(1,'A')   
----------------
a
```

Comment: Thanks MT0 its working :)